# Regex pattern matching [ ]

Tags: regex

I need to match a pattern such as this `[1712][***matchhere***]` where I just need the text between the second set of [ ].

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I have tried quite a bit of things. My latest is \[.*?()(?:(?!]).)* This matches the first and second [

Comment: When you add information, don't post a comment but [edit] the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pattern:

```
/\[\d+\]\[(.*)\]/
```

You may use sites like https://regex101.com/ to test your patterns.